# What is Tziporah's date of death?

Tags: history, yahrtzeit

What is the date of Tziporah (the wife of Moses)'s death and how did she die?

I already looked in the Jewish timeline encyclopedia.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score -1):

While Tziporah's death is not mentioned specifically in scriptures with pinpoint accuracy, according to [Numbers 32:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.32.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0) (NIV):

> "Because they have not followed me wholeheartedly, not one of those who were twenty years old or more when they came up out of Egypt will see the land I promised on oath to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob"

Based on this passage it could be assumed that she died prior to the Israelites entering Canaan; some time during the 40 years of wandering.

Comment: Seems plausible that that verse is only referring to males.

Comment: Also she didn't come out of Egypt @DoubleAA

Comment: Only the men who were between the ages of 20 and 60 (the ages for serving in the army) at the time of the meraglim were condemned to die. All the women and all the men above or below those ages did not necessarily die in the desert.

Comment: באוצר המדרשים [עמוד 372 – ואומנם כבר נודע שמדרשים אלו אינם מוסמכים במסורת] מובא שבזמן פטירת משה רבנו "אמר משה אל ה': אבי אשתי יתרו מת וגם אחי אהרן מת ואם אני אמות על מי אעזבם... התדמה כי אשכח את בניך אם יתפללו אלי כזה? והנה בניך יהיו לי לפקדון. ועתה נשק לבניך ולאשתך, יען כי קרבו אלה אשר יקחו את נפשך ולא תוסף לבא הנה..." משמע שחמיו מת ורק אשתו ציפורה עדיין נותרה בחיים. https://www.hidabroot.org/%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_kK24YugOhSWyCpGFizCQKczpiWICZsRXdT8NTJrlGKs-1635858136-0-gqNtZGzNAmWjcnBszQpR